# How can I fade-in divs on page load and fade them out in the opposite when leaving

Tags: jquery

I have 4 divs on a page, I need them to fade-in one after the other in a clockwise fashion, so not all at once. I also need them to fade out again in the opposite way they faded in when the user leaves the page however they need to have all faded away before the page redirects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the "Fading in" part:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4').animate({'opacity' : 0}, 0);
   fadeInDivs(['#div1', '#div2', '#div4', '#div3']);
});

function fadeInDivs(els) {
    e = els.pop();
    $(e).animate({'opacity' : 1}, 500, function(){
        if (els.length) fadeInDivs(els);
    })
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eks5L/5/

Edit:

The fading out part is a bit trickier though:

You could bind to the [unload Event](http://api.jquery.com/unload/), but chances are, that your animation won't finish before the browser redirects since there is no way to prevent or defer the unload.

You could also try to bind() a click handler to each <a> tag on the page, triggering the reverse fade-out animation before the redirect. It's gonna get messy, though.

Rough and untested suggestion:

```
$('a:not(".already-clicked")').live('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('already-clicked');
    callback = function(){$('a.already-clicked').click()};
    triggerFadeOutAnimation(callback);
});
```

Comment: thanks man how do you change it to go from div 1 to div 4 though?

Comment: Dan, just change the order in fadeInDivs(['#div1', '#div2', '#div3', '#div4']);

Comment: thanks a bunch for the help so far mate. really appreciate it. 
As for the page leaving code I know that this code will wait till the animations have finished before it redirects it just needs to be modified to remove the indervidual divs instead of the body

http://jsfiddle.net/VApgW/